# No sound from HDMI audio output (NVIDIA)

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, sound, alsa, hdmi

I can't get audio out from HDMI for my HTPC. Using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS - KODIbuntu on *Lenovo Ideacentre Q150* hardware with NVIDIA ION graphics. The problem appears to be that the PC doesn't recognize there is a monitor present. The NVIDIA HDMI audio device is recognized by both Ubuntu and ALSA. Most of the troubleshooting directions on the internet is very outdated and doesn't help.

```
administrator@MediaCenter:~$ cat /proc/asound/card1/eld#*
monitor_present         0
eld_valid               0

administrator@MediaCenter:~$ cat /proc/asound/NVidia/eld#*
monitor_present         0
eld_valid               0
```

I know the audio cable and TV work fine when I plug in a Roku device. It is not muted in AlsaMixer. The output from

```
uname -r; cat /proc/asound/version
play -l
aplay -L
```

is at http://paste2.org/ExL3jv1x

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with the same Lenovo ThinkCentre Q150 by switching to OpenELEC 7 Beta 3. [link](http://openelec.tv/get-openelec/category/53-x86-generic-intel-amd-nvidia-builds)  This version has been stable with only minor audio glitches. If you're heart is set on Kodibuntu, you could pull kernel and driver configuration settings from OpenELEC via SSH.

There were other posts online I found which pointed to a kernel issue which caused HDMI, to stop working.  I tried the default version of KodiBuntu, which failed HDMI.  I then did an upgrade and HDMI still didn't work.    I then attempted to upgrade the KodiBuntu kernel to a known working stock ubuntu version, and ran into dependency issues.  USB stopped working and I was unable to proceed.  After wasting several hours, OpenELEC 7 Beta 3 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

http://zentux.ca/enabling-hdmi-audio-with-ubuntu-and-kodibuntu/

This link seems to work on getting Radeon HDMI to work with Ubuntu and Kodibuntu and similar.